# How to make a conditional border with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Basically, I want to make a code that selects the Excel's cells according to the content.
I found to hard to explain in words, so I uploaded this image.

[image]

I want to select with a red border all the lines that contains the check mark. But if one line with the check mark is followed by another with the check mark, just do a big selection. (like I did manually in the image)

Any solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: how are you making the check marks? No need for VBA, use conditional formatting. That's what it is made for.

Comment: You're not going to be able to get borders around each contiguous run of checkmarks with conditional formatting, but I'd still recommend seeing if you can adjust your requirements because this would be a pain in VBA and simple (to achieve something similar to this) with conditional formatting.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried recording your steps and looking at the generated vba? You'll just need to loop through a range and check the value for the previous and next row.

Answer (score 2):

I know I said otherwise in the comments, but now that I've thought about it some more, this is entirely achievable with conditional formatting.

The idea is you'll set all the borders beforehand and then use conditional formatting to remove the borders that you don't want.

First, set the borders for each row how you want them to appear when there is no checkmark.

[image]

When the "Pass" column is "No", you want to remove the left and right border. Set up a conditional format using a formula rule to achieve this. Make sure to lock column D because the formula is being applied to multiple columns and you always want to look at column D.

[image]

If the current row has "Yes" in the pass column and the row below it also has "Yes", you want to remove the bottom border. You can use an additional conditional format to do this.

[image]

You'll need to cover a few more cases with additional conditional formulas, but this is the general idea.

[image]

Comment: Only a small problem. The last formula should be $D5=$D6

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be this:  First write a sub that puts a red border around the outside of any range.  It should look something like this:

```
Sub ApplyBorder(inputRg as Range)
    Call inputRg.BorderAround(Weight:=xlMedium, Color:=vbRed)
End Sub
```

Now we can iterate through our range.  If we find a check, include it in the range to be given a border.  If we find an x, then apply the red border around the range we have, and reset it to nothing.

```
Sub FormatTable()

    Dim AllTable As Range, oneRedRg As Range, oneRow As Range
    Dim iRow As Integer

    Set AllTable = GetTable

    For iRow = 1 To AllTable.Rows.Count
        Set oneRow = AllTable.Rows(iRow)
        If oneRow.Cells(1, 3) = True Then
            If oneRedRg Is Nothing Then     'if our current redRg is unset,
                Set oneRedRg = oneRow       'then this is the first one, so set it
            Else
                Set oneRedRg = Range(oneRedRg, oneRow)  'if it is already set, then expand oneRedRg to include this one
            End If
        Else
            if Not oneRedRg Is Nothing Then Call ApplyBorder(oneRedRg)  'if we find a range that need not be red, then
            Set oneRedRg = Nothing      'apply the border to our redRg and reset it to nothing
        End If
    Next iRow
    If Not oneRedRg Is Nothing Then Call ApplyBorder(oneRedRg)  'this last line captures a group of reds
                                                                'that are at the end of the table.
End Sub
```

I have excluded the "GetTable" function.  In my answer, GetTable returns the entire table to be iterated through, without the headers.  Also note that I changed the checks and x's to be values "True" or "False" in the spreadsheet for ease.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

CF with these four rules may serve, where what is not visible is the code point for the ticks (maybe '252'):

[image: SO23619627 example]

and the ranges adjusted, if necessary, to suit.